# first azsphere login with a guest user as global admin

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-sphere

Given two independent organizations Ciccio and Pierino, Ciccio has an AAD of which bepi@pierino.com is a guest user with the role of global administrator, Ciccio wants bepi@pierino.com to create the first Azure Sphere tenant... it is possible for bepi@pierino.com do the first "azsphere login" inside the Ciccio Active Directory? Such as?

this is the error message encountered

azsphere login
error: You could not be authenticated: AADSTS650051: Using application 'Azure Sphere API' is currently not supported for your organization pierino.com because it is in an unmanaged state. An administrator needs to claim ownership of the company by DNS validation of pierino.com before the application Azure Sphere API can be provisioned.
Trace ID: 3a0aad18-5fe6-45cc-89ea-6989317a1400
Correlation ID: 9852e07b-73f5-4b62-a710-258c1bbaa740
Timestamp: 2019-09-11 14:45:25Z
error: Command failed in 00:00:45.7810542.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Sphere team is making a few improvements to this area soon. Hope you can wait for a few more weeks on this issue.